# AWS Greengrass lambda function not running

Tags: aws-lambda, execution, aws-iot-greengrass

2021-01-14T17:47:36.617Z [INFO] (Copier) Greengrass_HelloWorld: Startup script exited. {exitCode=1, serviceInstance=0, serviceName=Greengrass_HelloWorld, currentState=STARTING}
2021-01-14T17:47:36.639Z [INFO] (pool-2-thread-57) Greengrass_HelloWorld: shell-runner-start. {scriptName=services.Greengrass_HelloWorld.lifecycle.shutdown.script, serviceInstance=0, serviceName=Greengrass_HelloWorld, currentState=BROKEN, command=["/greengrass/v2/packages/artifacts/aws.greengrass.LambdaLauncher/2.0.3/lambda-l..."]}
2021-01-14T17:47:36.771Z [WARN] (Copier) Greengrass_HelloWorld: stderr. 2021/01/14 17:47:36 error loading lambda process: could not load container from /greengrass/v2/work/Greengrass_HelloWorld/work/worker/0/container: container "lambda" does not exist. {scriptName=services.Greengrass_HelloWorld.lifecycle.shutdown.script, serviceInstance=0, serviceName=Greengrass_HelloWorld, currentState=BROKEN}

After deployment i am seeing the above error. Any idea what could cause this issue

Comment: Have we found a fix for this yet?

Comment: I am also getting the same exception. Not able to fix this.